# Access an element's events object from Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

In the page exists a bound event like so:

```
$('form#signin_form').submit(function() {
  // ...
})
```

In the Chrome extension I find the form:

```
$form = $("form").has(':password').first()
```

But asking for events bound on the form comes up undefined (this is loaded through the content_scripts part of the manifest, not injected in the page):

```
$.data($form, 'events') // undefined
```

Is it not possible to get event data from elements from a content script?

Comment: At which moment do you bind the event? If it's at `onload`, this may happen after the moment the content_script runs. Do you use `run_at` in the [manifest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) to set  it to something other than `document_idle`, which is default.

Comment: The `submit` handler is on ready. The query for the `form` is also on ready, but in the content script. If it finds the `form` before the event is bound, will the events object be empty?

Comment: Actually, if I call `$form.submit()` from the extension, it seems to bypass the bound event. Doing the same in console works like you'd expect.

Comment: I think, there can be a problem, in which order the two `onready` handlers are invoked. It may happen, that content script is invoked before original document's handler. All handlers are executed in the order of their binding - please, make sure you bind content script's handler after initial document's one.

Comment: Code running on the webpage and code running on the content script live in different contexts. This affects all the structures jQuery uses for event handling. The jQuery instance running on the content script can't be aware of event handlers defined on the webpage context.

Comment: @rsanchez This seems to be correct. If this was an answer I would accept it.